# Buscar texto numerico exacto en cadena

Tags: php, regex

Tengo que buscar un número exacto dentro de una cadena de texto, pero no me vale que el numero sea parte de otro.

En una iteración, por ejemplo tengo que buscar el valor 105 exactamente, no sé lo que puede tener por delante o por detrás.

```
$texto = ["micadena_33_mastexto", "micadena_105_mastexto", "micadena2105_mastexto", "micadena_1110545_mastexto", "otracadena105"]
```

En este caso solo me tendrá que devolver

"micadena_105_mastexto" y "otracadena105"

Recorriendo el array he probado con

```
strpos($texto[x], '105);
```

y no consigo que solo me devuelva esos dos elemento

en otra iteración debería buscar otro valor, por ejemplo "10" y en este caso no tendría que devolver nada.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer con [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php), usando esta expresión regular `/([^0-9]|^)$find([^0-9]|$)/`, con la cual podrás encontrar solamente los casos en que `$find` exista como valor numérico, sin otros dígitos antes o después.

Por ejemplo:

```
$texto = ["1105micadena_33_mastexto", "micadena_105_mastexto", "micadena2105_mastexto", "micadena_1110545_mastexto", "otracadena105"];
$find=105;
$matches=array();
foreach ($texto as $v)
{
    if ( preg_match("/([^0-9]|^)$find([^0-9]|$)/",$v) ) 
    {
        $matches[]=$v;
    }      
}
var_dump($matches);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(21) "micadena_105_mastexto"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "otracadena105"
}
```

Comment: Ok, gracias, esto me vale

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que el número que buscamos se llama `x`.
Entonces podemos utilizar:

- `Negative Lookbehind`: Necesitamos encontrar `x` que no este precedida por un número.
  Es decir: `(?<![0-9])x`
- `Negative Lookahead`: Necesitamos encontrar `x` que no este seguida por un número.
  Es decir: `x(?![0-9])`

Si combinamos ambos, la RegEx sería:

```
/(?<![0-9])x(?![0-9])/
```

#### Solución:

```php
<?php

function encontrar_numero($numero, $textos) {
    $resultado = [];
    foreach ($textos as $texto) {
        if (preg_match('/(?<![0-9])'.$numero.'(?![0-9])/', $texto)) {
            $resultado[] = $texto;
        }
    }
    return $resultado;
}

//
$textos = ["micadena_33_mastexto", "micadena_105_mastexto", "micadena2105_mastexto", "micadena_1110545_mastexto", "otracadena105", "105otracadena"];
$numero = 105;
var_export(encontrar_numero($numero, $textos));
```

Resultado:

```
array (
  0 => 'micadena_105_mastexto',
  1 => 'otracadena105',
  2 => '105otracadena',
)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/e0ad52)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usa la función preg_match de PHP para eso.
Y luego usar \b es un límite de palabra en la expresión regular, lo que significa que coincidirá con 105 solo si está rodeado de no dígitos.

```
$texto = ["micadena_33_mastexto", "micadena_105_mastexto", "micadena2105_mastexto", "micadena_1110545_mastexto", "otracadena105"];
$numeroBuscado = 105;
$resultados = [];

foreach ($texto as $cadena) {
    if (preg_match('/\b' . $numeroBuscado . '\b|^' . $numeroBuscado . '\b|\b' . $numeroBuscado . '$/', $cadena) || strpos($cadena, '_' . $numeroBuscado . '_') !== false) {
        $resultados[] = $cadena;
    }}
```

Comment: Probando lo que comentas genera la siguiente expresión regular  "/\b105\b|^105\b|\b105$/" pero devuelve un array vacío.  array(0) { }

Comment: Intenta hacer esto he modificado el código.

Comment: Si, ya devuelve algo pero no me vale, no devuelve este valor ""otracadena105""

Comment: Entiendo que debería ser algo así

$pattern = "/^[0-9]105^[0-9]$/";

Que delante y detrás que no vaya un dígito, pero esto no funciona